# Click link store variable pass to select on new page

Tags: jquery, variables, select

I have links on a few pages which stores the name of a Room

```
<a href="/booking/" class="book" data-book="Room One">
<a href="/booking/" class="book" data-book="Room Two">
```

On clicking I want to store the data variable and pass the Room Name to a form on a new page and preselect the select option.

I have tried this:

```
$('.book').on('click', function(){
var roomSuiteLink = $(this).data('book');
});
```

I want the value of 'roomSuiteLink' to be the selected select option. Ive been trying this with no luck:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null;
}
var roomSuite = getURLParameter('roomSuiteLink');           
$('#my-select').val( roomSuite );
```

Then on the new page I have a select menu:

```
<select id="my-select" name="my-select">
<option value="Room One">Room One</option>
<option value="Room Two">Room Two</option>
</select>
```

I dont want to add anything to the URL like this: /booking/?room name. Can I do this with jquery or do I need a session variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the selected property to true

```
$('#my-select [value="' + roomSuite + '"]').prop('selected', true)
```

[JSFiddle result](http://fiddle.jshell.net/r4Lu0pr9/3/show/light/?roomSuiteLink=Room%20Two)

Comment: Thanks for that. I see on JSFiddle its working. If I add "?roomSuiteLink=Room Name" to the booking URL like such: /booking/?roomSuiteLink=Room Name - it does work.  I wanted to avoid this but Ill check if this is an option. Ideally, as mentioned previously, I wanted to avoid  this. Difster said below that I have to use cookies or sessions - can anyone confirm that?

Comment: @Rob you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awRqBw

Comment: Hey Miquel - thanks again. The issue now is that using event.preventDefault() stops the page from going to the /booking/ page. The links <a href="#" class="book" data-book="Room One">Room One</a> are on different pages.